# Traffic growth forecast: showing the change of linear regression

Tags: fitting, time-series, finance

The following picture shows a changement in the trend of data. (The data used are available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE/edit#gid=0)).

Is there any tool that can show this change of trend?

[image]

Until now I managed to show even more clearly that a single linear model is not good for investigating this series of data

[image]

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. ( I suspect you know how to fit to parts of the data ) . Are you looking for some way to automatically identify the bi-linear nature of the data?

Comment: @george2079: yes! exactly!! Doesn it exist? Or at least a way to plot different linear regression in the same graph (the moving average is not the best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a Mathematica question, but here are some thoughts.

1. I doubt you will be able to distinguish between a break in trend and a logarithmic trend. Take the log of the data and see if that has a linear trend instead.
2. There are plenty of ways to test for and find a structural break. Have a look at some [basic resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break) on this. The CUSUM test is not built into Mathematica, but you might be able to find suitable tests in the in-built installation of R, using [`RLink`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html).
3. If you know when the break occurs, then it is simply a matter of adding an additional regressor, namely a variable that is zero before the break date and trends after that. Significance of this variable is a test of whether there is a break at this point, and is in essence what most break-point tests do. You can then visualise the fitted values of the regression as a comparator to the original data, or do any of the other statistical / econometric tests built into Mathematica and/or the in-built R implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! knowing the word "structural break" is opening a world to me. Can I ask you also which tool is best for this kind of Analysis? Matlab? R? What about Wolfram Data Science Platform and Wolfram Finance Platform?

Comment: I don't think there is a "best" tool for a relatively straightforward econometric analysis like this. You could do it in R, in Mathematica-plus-R, or eViews, or any number of econometric tools.